# OpenCV, Python, Blob Detection. How to avoid reflective surface

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using blob detection to detect some black stones on a plate. Most of the time it works fine, but when it comes to the smooth surface one such as the thresholding image below, it won't work. As shown on the right side of the picture that the reflective surface is quite large so that the detection won't consider it as a blob. Anyway to go around it? Thanks.

I used cv2.SimpleBlobDetector for this tracking. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using the cv2.findcontour() function and selecting for the largest member of the contour hierarchy.